# ¿Cómo habilitar el autocompletado de código Node.js en VSCode?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

He instalado Visual Studio Code y Node.js y ambos básicamente funcionan, pero la función de autocompletar no funciona (completamente). Ya que si escribo .find no me sale un lista con las opciones de autocompletado

Ya que he visto que mucho les sale así:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

Y a mi me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene alguna solución para que me aparezca el autocompletado para mi código.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica estos dos puntos:

1. Verificar la extensión de lenguaje: Asegúrate de que estés utilizando una extensión de lenguaje adecuada para Node.js en Visual Studio Code. La extensión oficial de JavaScript (que también incluye soporte para Node.js) es muy popular y se recomienda su uso. Puedes instalarla desde la pestaña de Extensiones (Ctrl + Shift + X) buscando "JavaScript" y seleccionando "JavaScript (Standard Style)" de los resultados.
2. Verificar la configuración de IntelliSense: Asegúrate de que la configuración de IntelliSense en Visual Studio Code esté habilitada. Puedes hacerlo abriendo la configuración de usuario (File -> Preferences -> Settings) y asegurándote de que la opción "Editor: Suggest" esté habilitada.